# XCode fails to create archive with 'unable to spawn process /usr/bin/make' error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-archive

Having trouble while creating archive of ios project (swift).
The project has a build target, which requires `/usr/bin/make` to be set as build tool, but while trying to create an archive I constantly get `error: unable to spawn process '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory)`
The make file exists in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/` and also added to `PATH` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite XCode provided only `error: unable to spawn process '/usr/bin/make' (No such file or directory)` message, the real reason was in the same target's **External Build Tool Configuration** `Directory` path value. It required different directories for debug and release builds

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue when I am trying to run the code in a device. I didn't quite understand the answer. Could you please help me here?

Comment: @VishnuPrasannan hey :)
In my case the following thing worked: in target's `Info` tab the `Directory` path depends on debug/release configuration. 
So I created `$CUSTOM_BUILD_PATH` for each configuration and set it as `Directory` value. You'll have to find out what `$CUSTOM_BUILD_PATH` works for your particular target

Comment: @potato_fog Could you please explain this more in detail in your answer? Ideally with an example, as it's very hard to understand what you mean. Thank you